# rich:calendar set default date to today's date

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have an entity class and have a date variable inside the class which is filled by `<rich:calendar>` in JSF page. I want to see the today's date by default, when the JSF page is loaded. How can I do that?

Here is my code.

```
<rich:calendar 
        cellWidth="24px" 
        cellHeight="22px"
        datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy" 
        id="notificationDate" 
        inputClass="input"
        inputStyle="width:73%;"
        value="#{correspondenceHome.instance.notificationDate}">
</rich:calendar>
```

```
// notificationdate
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "NotificationDate", length = 0)
public Date getNotificationDate() {
    return notificationDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just preset the model behind the `value` attribute to the desired value.

E.g. directly after preparing/obtaining the `instance`:

```
instance.setNotificationDate(new Date());
```

Comment: That worked thanks. But is there any other way to do that in the jsf? wtih richfaces features?

Comment: It isn't the responsibility of the view to construct the model.